# Read XML from a webbrowser component

Tags: xml, vb.net, webbrowser-control, microsoft-dynamics

I have an application that gives an individual a preview of the XML page in a webbrowser component after NavUserPassword authentication and then shows a side panel that parses it into meaningful data. However, I cannot seem to find an effective way to export all the XML out of the webbrowser component via a string.

An example of the webpage without authentication is, https://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/

I have this code below, though it throws an MssingMemberExeption "Public member 'XMLDocument' on type 'HTMLDocumentClass' not found."

```vb
Private Sub WebBrowserAuthEx1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowserAuthExt1.DocumentCompleted
    Dim doc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
    doc.LoadXml(WebBrowserAuthExt1.Document.DomDocument.XMLDocument) ' I throw MssingMemberExeption
    MessageBox.Show(doc.Value.ToString)
End Sub
```

How can I get this XML DOM in webbrowser to give me all the XML?

It is the same as a normal webbrowser, but the XML must come out of it as it is authenticated, and I don't want to authenticate another stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the example Url that you provided, you can obtain the xml with something like the following code:

```
Dim xmlText As String = WebBrowser1.Document.All.Item(0).InnerText
```

---

Edit: The OP pointed out (in a rejected edit) that the text returned by the above returns a "- " on some lines.  This is a consequence of the source being formatted as tree structure and not as *pure* XML.  Their solution was the following:

```
' It also includes the code folding dashes, use the below to sanitize the data.
If xmlText <> Nothing Then
    xmlText = xmlText.Replace("- ", "")
End If
```

This usage of `Replace` risks unintended modification of data and I just wanted to suggest the following alternative that limits potential changes only to the beginning of lines.

```
Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder(xmlText.Length)
Using sr As New System.IO.StringReader(xmlText)
    Do While sr.Peek <> -1
        Dim line As String = sr.ReadLine()
        Dim startOfLineIndex As Int32 = sb.Length
        sb.AppendLine(line)
        If sb.Chars(startOfLineIndex) = "-"c Then sb.Chars(startOfLineIndex) = " "c
    Loop
End Using
xmlText = sb.ToString()
```

Comment: @DevSushi, your edit was rejected, but I got the message.  Please look at the modified answer as your solution has some risks.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the built-in `System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser` control you can use the [`DocumentText` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documenttext) to get the website's HTML (basically XML) code.

```vb
doc.LoadXml(WebBrowserAuthExt1.DocumentText)
```

Comment: I get an XmlException 'Reference to undeclared entity 'nbsp'. Line #, position #.' on this line of code, does XmlDocument need the XML to be sanatized?

Comment: @DevSushi : It appears so. `&nbsp;` is a non-breaking space in HTML. I'm not entirely sure how Tn's solution works but when using `InnerText` such entities are usually converted for you, so it solves that problem.